# Facebook Like Box plugin recently stopped showing the Stream

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

On our site http://www.viva.org/learn.aspx the Like Box plugin has recently stopped showing the Stream. Even after generating new code via the developer site:

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FViva-Learn%2F203492233024242&width=292&height=590&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&appId=8426528154

it still doesn't show!

The fb page it's trying to share is: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Viva-Learn/203492233024242

Another Like Box on the site is still working however, which is sharing the page: https://www.facebook.com/VivaStandOut (Like Box @ http://www.viva.org/standout.aspx)

Why would one work and not the other?

Thanks!

Comment: It happened during checkout of different browsers. At first I thought the code broke. But your post clarified the issue. Sure wish FB would provide this sort of documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed it too.  It seems facebook is hiding any streams that are a certain age.  I think its 30 days but I am not sure.   Once you have a more recent post it will show that new post then a little section below it that says "Show More" with a little down arrow which will reveal your older posts.

Comment: We just figure that out too, how annoying! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem for my website, its due to not updating the page for long time.
Just post the update and it instantly start showing in the like box plugin on my website, and also make sure display stream check box is checked while generating code.

Comment: There was no need to include a link to your website. Please do not do that in the future, or your post could be deleted as spam.

Comment: @andrew-barber, ok thanks. As I am new to stackoverflow made the mistake. Would take care of it.