# Like Box not showing current stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have trolled every question and could not find one to fix my problem. The like box stream stopped working back on July 1st and I cannot get it to work again. Below is the old code.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/AllStar-MMA-Tours/133893883351736" data-width="300" data-show-faces="true" data-border-color="white" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

Comment: Can someone please help me with this!

Comment: It may have something to do with the stream having no recent posts, but I'm having the same problem and am currently researching it. Mine has had recent posts that don't show up in the stream; the stream is empty/doesn't show. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684449/facebook-like-box-plugin-recently-stopped-showing-the-stream Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue on a client site, home4animals dot org / facebook. The only thing that I could think of that had changed was the fact the site had moved to a different machine and thus DNS had changed, so I created a new facebook app.  Problem still remained, it was a long shot.

I then checked on our company website where the Facebook like box is working, and discovered that there was no appId parameter.  Removing this resolved the problem, and stream now shows as expected.  I haven't changed that particular code for 8 months so something at the Facebook end has changed in my opinion.

```
diff DownloadFacebookJS.ss DownloadFacebookJS.ss.orig 
6c6
<   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1;";
---
>   js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=$FacebookApplicationID;";
8c8
< }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
---
> }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
\ No newline at end of file
```